HTML form using Google App Scripts MailApp Email Notification not working
I bootstrapped this code from github - click here if you would like to see the original tutorial
Currently the MailApp.sendemail function is not working.
Note: in my deployed App Script I replaced "enter email" with "myemail@gmail.com" however I did not change anything else.
Can anyone help me work out what the issue is?
 var sheetName = 'Sheet1' //-------------------------
 var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

 function intialSetup () {
   var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
 }

 function doPost (e) {
   var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
   lock.tryLock(10000)

   try {
     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
     var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

     var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
     var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

     var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
       return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date().toLocaleString() : e.parameter[header]
     })

     sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

     // Send email notification
     var emailSubject = "type email subject"; //-------------------------
     var emailBody = "type body";  //-------------------------
     var email = "enter email"; //-------------------------
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, emailSubject, emailBody);

     return ContentService
       .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
   }

   catch (e) {
     return ContentService
       .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
   }

   finally {
     lock.releaseLock()
   }
 }


Please add some spreadsheet sample data, the deployment settings and the textual error message.

Managed to work it out. I just needed to re-deploy the app script. Rookie mistake.
